# How to handle multiple value error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
    
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

these are the two differant error so how we can throw error like

for first ValueError I want to print ==> not enough value
and for second ValueError print ==> extra values

how I can handle this error using exception method or anything other in python

Comment: You can catch the `ValueError` exception, and then throw your own custom exception based on the error message.

Comment: Where do you get the values from?  Maybe you can inspect/convert that object and build a message based on its length rather than parsing the error message.

Comment: overloading a function/class method? just add *args  and remove the predefined parameter

Comment: Why do you need to print your own message? Doesn't the existing error message say the same thing you want to print?

Comment: does the ValueError come from your code, or a 3rd party?  if it's from your code it would be better to re-write it to throw different custom exception for each case.  If you can't control what error is thrown then the only way is as @tromgy suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
a = (1,2,3)  # a = (1,)
try:
    b,c = a   #Try to unpack
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    if('not enough values to unpack' in str(e)):
        print("not enough value")
    if('too many values' in str(e)):
        print("extra values")
```